# How to remote debug on chrome mobile on IOS devices

Tags: ios, debugging, google-chrome, mobile

Anyone here knows if it's possible to remote debug on Chrome Mobile on IOS Devices? I have a site with a div with 100% width and height and position fixed. For some reason this element stays at the wrong position.

I know it's possible to debug safari but the problem just happens on chrome and on ios devices.

Thanks
Angelo

Comment: @jycr753 I have saw this post, it's from 2012 and the answer doesn't help me at all. I know it's possible to debug safari, but that's not what I need. I need to debug chrome.

Comment: There is not such a thing far i know, have you tried doing in it in a android device? since it is the same thing...
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: @jycr753 I did, unfortunately the problem just happens on chrome ios, android devices works perfect. I'm trying now Adobe Edge Inspect. But It's not working the way I would like to.

Comment: I can't see any option like that to do it true xcode... :S damn this looks odd....

Comment: @jycr753 Problem solved using Adobe Edge Inspect. Thanks

Comment: nice that it is something good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/).

Instructions on how to use it is available at the link below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Platform/Gaia/Weinre_As_Remote_Debugger

It worked for me on Mac/iPhone/Chrome

It also works on Mac/Android/Chrome and firefox browsers too.

If your code/files are on a remote device, make sure you run the tool (weinre) on the remote system.